# Poisson Convergence Example

Tags: poisson-distribution, convergence

For any $n\ge1,$ let $X_{n1},...,X_{nn}$ be independent with 
$$P\{X_{nk}=5\}=1-P\{X_{nk}=0\}=p_{nk}, \ k=1,...,n$$.

Assume that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \max_{1\le k \le n} p_{nk}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} p_{nk} =2$$.

Find the limit in distribution of $S_n=X_{n1}+\cdots+X_{nn}$.

I know this converges to a poisson distribution. This would easy to show using the characteristic function if the random variables were identically distributed but they are not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove such assertions using rare event laws. See for example Theorem 7.13 of [this reference](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~roch/grad-prob/roch-prob-7web.pdf). The proof follows through using characteristic functions, since your random variables are essentially Bernoulli and independent after rescaling $Y_i:=X_i/5$, and will have characteristic function $1+p_{n,m}(e^{it}-1)$. You will use the maximum assertion and the sum convergence assertion when expanding the product of characteristic functions, to bound higher order terms.